# GridView row not updating, text from textbox in gridview edit template not coming

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have grid view in which I want to update row but it is not happening. The datasource is a DataTable. Please help.

Below is the markup

```
<asp:GridView ID="GrdV" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"   
   OnRowEditing="GrdV_RowEditing"  OnRowUpdating="GrdV_RowUpdating">

 <Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Clip Description">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblDescrptn" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>'>
            </asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="descTbx" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>'>
            </asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

   <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />

 </Columns>
```

and this is code behind

```
    protected void GrdV_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

        // Retrieve the row being edited.
      int index = GrdV.EditIndex;
        GridViewRow row = GrdV.Rows[index];           
        TextBox t1 = row.FindControl("descTbx") as TextBox;

        DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["tmdataTable"];

        dt.Rows[index]["Description"] = t1.Text; //Description is a column of my DataTable
        dt.AcceptChanges();
        GrdV.EditIndex = -1;
        GrdV.DataSource = dt;
        GrdV.DataBind();

    }
```

On debugging , I find that textbox is passing empty string `t1.Text =""` even after I have filled textbox with new values.
I think the error is in line

```
TextBox t1 = row.FindControl("descTbx") as TextBox;
```

PageLoad code

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GrdV.DataSource = Session["tmdataTable"];
            GrdV.DataBind();
        }


        DataTable Finaldt = getTable();

        GrdV.DataSource = Finaldt;
        GrdV.DataBind();
        Session["tmdataTable"] = Finaldt;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter your code a bit and check. Change `EditIndex` to `e.RowIndex`

```
protected void GrdV_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GrdV.Rows[e.RowIndex]; // this line is changed      
    TextBox t1 = row.FindControl("descTbx") as TextBox;

    DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["tmdataTable"];

    dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Description"] = t1.Text; //Description is a column of my DataTable
    dt.AcceptChanges();
    GrdV.EditIndex = -1;
    GrdV.DataSource = dt;
    GrdV.DataBind();
}
```

Have you done this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        GrdV.DataSource = Session["tmdataTable"];
        GrdV.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: No effect . Still t1.text is blank

Comment: still nothing, same problem

Comment: but that will throw error ..lots of logic after isnot postback , why am i getting blank value from textbox , i simply can't understand..thnks for taking time to help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27689/discussion-between-praveen-nambiar-and-mudassir-hasan)

Comment: there seems nothing wrong with the updated code....the thing is when you are clicking the `Update` button...the `textbox` value is getting cleared before the `gridview` updates with the new value. which means on `page_load` something goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`EditIndex` isn't available, you need e.RowIndex from the `GridViewUpdateEventArgs`

```
// Retrieve the row being edited.
DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["tmdataTable"];
GridViewRow row = GrdV.Rows[e.RowIndex];
TextBox t1 = row.FindControl("descTbx") as TextBox;

dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Description"] = t1.Text; //Description is a column of my DataTable
dt.AcceptChanges();
GrdV.EditIndex = -1;
GrdV.DataSource = dt;
GrdV.DataBind();
```

Comment: No effect . still blank value passed in t1.Text .

Comment: Try changing `GrdV.DataSource = dt;` to `GrdV.DataSource = Session["tmdataTable"];` but then again, that looks like what Praveen said

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void GrdV_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
         if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
        {
        // Retrieve the row being edited.
      int index = GrdV.EditIndex;
        GridViewRow row = GrdV.Rows[index];           
        TextBox t1 = row.FindControl("descTbx") as TextBox;

        DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["tmdataTable"];

        dt.Rows[index]["Description"] = t1.Text; //Description is a column of my DataTable
        dt.AcceptChanges();
        GrdV.EditIndex = -1;
        GrdV.DataSource = dt;
        GrdV.DataBind();
        }
    }
```